# Getting error while adding jquery library in asp.net 4.0 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-4.0

I created an application in asp.net4.0 and used master-page in this application.

I took reference to a j query js library file on master-page which is in Scripts folder.
When i write some jquery code in child page i got an error(this page is in Videos folder).
but when i reference js file on this child page then its working fine.

So do i have to link this js file on every child pages?

Can't we do it only by reference js file on master page.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have both Master and child page in same folder?

Comment: one child page in the same folder and others are in other folder

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I faced this issue once.

I dont exactly remember if the following lines fixed the issue but you may try once:

In the script source, mention the src as:

```
src=<% ResolveClinetUrl("~/scripts/script.js")%>
```

which means in the root -> there is folder named scripts -> in which there is a script file named script.js

Comment: I do the same but when i click on a link on master page(which redirect me to child page) i got error: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: Okay I have one more work around. See my next answer. I am writing, please hold!

Answer (score 0):

*Read carefully* :

> (F) means folder

- Root - > Scripts(F) -> your script file(s) here
- Root -> Videos(F) -> your page(s) here

Now, if you are on the page that's in the Videos folder and you need to access the script which's kept in the Scripts folder. What you need to do is:

1. Go one level back in the hierarchy, and when you are one level back,
   you can access the folder Scripts and thus the scripts file placed
   there.
2. To go one level back the heirarchy, you need to write " ../ "
   in the src attribute.

*Considering the above explanation, now try this:*

```
src = "../Scripts/script.js"
```